# Simple bijectiveness question

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f$'s image set is $g$'s domain and vice versa, does that imply that their domains have a 1-1 correspondence? That $f$ and $g$ are both bijective mappings? Are my questions even meaningful?

Edit:
My question stems from this example from David Brannan's First Course in Mathematical Analysis.
I don't feel entirely comfortable with his argument that f is a one-to-one correspondence. (I do know how to show this by showing surjectivity(which is assumed here) and injectivity separately.)

[image]

Comment: And yes, your questions are meaningful.

Comment: In your update, you say you don't feel comfortable with the argument, but could you be more specific about what you're not comfortable with? Do you have specific questions about the argument?  What do you mean by "which is assumed here"; the argument constructs an inverse function for $f$, and does not "assume" that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I'm not entirely convinced that f is a 1-1 correspondence based on the argument (which seems simimlar to the technique of proving that two sets are equal). Does my distillation of the argument thus far show that I've misunderstood it?

Comment: The author doesn't assume surjectivity, but shows it, although perhaps the writing could have made this more explicit.   "Also, for each $y\in(0,\infty)$, we have $x=1-\dfrac1{y}\in(-\infty,1)$."   The point is that $f(x)=y$, so $y$ is in the image.

Comment: @JonasMeyer But since f's codomain is unspecified, we had to assume that it is $(0,\infty)$, in order for $f^{-1}$ to be definable. The step that you highlight further shows that the range falls within the entirety of the codomain, i.e. that $f$ is surjective. But what I meant was that there had to be, in the first place, the initial assumption that that was the codomain in the first place. (In this textbook, the author claims that $f^{-1}$ is defined as long as it is injective. I.e. all functions are being automatically assumed to be surjective.)

Comment: Ryan: Would you have been happier with a formulation like, "Let $f:(-\infty,1)\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.  Then $f$ is injective and has image $(0,\infty)$.  If we take $(0,\infty)$ to be the codomain of $f$ instead of $\mathbb R$, then $f$ has an inverse function." ?  It is easier to formulate as in the given example, and the mathematical content is the same.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks. I guess I was trying to point out that, in the absence of the codomain being explicitly stated, we assume range=codomain, and hence assume surjectivity. In all the other examples in this textbook (that don't involve finding an explicit rule for $f^{−1}$), this is exactly what the author assumes: that $f$'s injectiveness is sufficient for inverse to exist. I mean, suppose $f$'s codomain is $\mathbb R$, but the information has been carelessly omitted. Then the given argument clearly does not prove that $f$ has an inverse;

Comment: ... it shows the rule and domain of $f$'s inverse, conditional upon $f$'s codomain being the set of positive reals. I agree that I'm being pedantic, but I disagree that the mathematical content is exactly the same (since one involves an implicit assumption and the other doesn't require the assumption as the information has been explcitly specified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $D_f,D_g$, respectively, the domain of $f$, and the domain of $g$. Your assumption says that $f:D_f\to D_g$ is onto, and that $g:D_g\to D_f$ is onto.

Now, assuming the axiom of choice, if there is a surjection $\pi:A\to B$, then there is an injection $\tau:B\to A$ (for each $b\in B$, we can choose one of its preimages in $A$). So, this gives us injections from $D_g$ into $D_f$ and viceversa.

The [Bernstein-Cantor-Schroeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) theorem ensures now that there is a bijection between $D_f$ and $D_g$.

---

On the other hand, $f$ and $g$ themselves do not need to be bijective, or injective. For example, we could have $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ be the function that multiplies a number by $10$ and discards the integer part, if any. So, for example, $f(.34)=f(.04)=.4$. Clearly, $f$ is onto but not $1$-$1$, and we can take $g=f$.

---

Now: The use of choice is essential to get a positive answer to whether $D_f$ and $D_g$ are in bijection. Without choice, we can have sets $A$ and $B$ of incomparable size, and surjections in both directions. (We can even have both $A$ and $B$ to be quotients of $\mathbb R$ in an appropriate model of set theory where the full axiom of choice fails.) See this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem) for closely related issues, and links to examples, or see this [blog post](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/580-some-choiceless-results-2/) of mine.

---

With regards to your example, the function $f$ is clearly defined on $(-\infty,1)$. It is also meaningful at other points, but we do not care. The function admits an inverse, which is obtained by solving $f(x)=y$ for $x$ in terms of $y$. That there is an inverse tells us that $f$ is injective (otherwise, for some values of $y$ we would not have been able to find a single $x$). Clearly, $f$ is onto the domain of this inverse function (by definition: The values of $y$ we are considering are precisely those for which $f(x)=y$ for some $x$). So what remains is to find the image of $f$. That's what's done at the end of the displayed image.

Of course, one could have gone at this differently, and show first that $f$ is injective by directly checking that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ gives us $x_1=x_2$. Then, we could find the range of $f$ very much as in the final 5 lines. Having identified the image $I$, by definition $f$ is onto $I$. Since it is injective, this directly shows that $f$ is a bijection between its domain and its image.

Comment: THANK YOU for your extremely spot-on answer. It has simultaneously cleared up several doubts and questions I had before but wasn't able to articulate. You are my mind-reader.

Comment: But if being able to solve $f(x)=y$ for $x$ in terms of $y$ automatically implies that f is injective, is checking that  $f(x_1)=f(x_2) => x_1=x_2$ redundant then?

Comment: Ryan, you'd do one or the other (either solving for $x$ thus finding an explicit formula for the inverse, or checking directly that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\to x_1=x_2$), there is no need to do both. Clayton suggests a third approach (if $f'(x)>0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing, so it must be injective), and surely there are other ways. What matters here is that injectivity is verified somehow.

Comment: OIC. So if we're being asked to find the inverse (if it exists), and it so happens to exist, then there is no need to check for injectivity because that would be implied in converting the formula from y in terms of x to x in terms of y, correct?

Comment: (That said, the argument in the displayed image uses the explicit formula for the inverse function to identify the range of $f$, so it makes sense, for this approach, to use this as well to verify injectivity, since we end up computing the inverse anyway.)

Comment: Correct, that would suffice.

Comment: OK now I'm confused again. In the displayed image, isn't the entire portion of the proof starting from "Also, for each y" redundant? After all, by this point, we have pretty much validly defined the inverse (found its formula plus domain), so this already implies that the inverse exists, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, this is a little subtlety: The line above shows that the image is *contained* in $(0,\infty)$. It could be, in principle, that the image is not all of $(0,\infty)$. The argument that begins with "Also" shows that every point in $(0,\infty)$ is in the image, that is, the image *contains* $(0,\infty)$. Putting the two together gives that the image is precisely $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I understand that the line above shows that the image is merely contained... However, I disagree with that line (and thus ignored the "contained" bit) , as I feel that what was before it sufficiently showed that the image is all of $(0,\infty)$. That is how I would normally demonstrate the domain of of the inverse anyway-- by manipulating the inequalities. Is this inadequate and have my workings been incomplete? (Since continuity of the simple functions are pretty obvious, I usually neglect to point it out.)

Comment: Something would be missing if that is all you do, I think.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

No; consider $f:[-1,1]\to[0,1]$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ and $g:[0,1]\to[-1,1]$ defined by $g(x)=2x-1$. One of them is bijective in this case, but not both.

As Jonas Meyer points out below, given AC, the domains will have a $1$-$1$ correspondence.

EDIT: The author's approach is certainly not how I would approach it; I'd calculate $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}>0\textrm{ for all }x\in(-\infty,1).$$However, as it stands, I think your revised question has best been answered by Andres; this is just an alternative method which I find more straightforward.

Comment: But the domains are in one-to-one correspondence. This will always be the case (at least if AC is assumed).

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes, that is true; I was just pointing out that the functions need not be bijective.

Comment: What does AC mean?

Comment: @Ryan: Axiom of Choice

Comment: @JonasMeyer Hi all, thank you for your interesting responses (I hadn't realised that my question was so deep). Would you mind to take a look at my edited question and respond to my specific elaboration?